# how to transform csv files of various encoding into utf-8

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have 95 small CSV files downloaded from web. Their schemas are supposed to be very similar. I am trying to concatenate them with Python pandas, but when calling `pd.read_csv`, the various encoding of those files are causing problems, and I am not sure what's the best way to transform them into consistent encoding, e.g. utf-8. The encodings include

```
ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode English text, with CRLF line terminators
Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF, CR line terminators
UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) English text, with CRLF line terminators
UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
```

The above list is generated with

```
file -b *.csv | sort | uniq
```

Comment: You can use the 3rd-party [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) module to do encoding detection in Python. And your system should have the standard `chardet` and `iconv` programs if you want to do conversions via the shell.

Comment: Thanks. will check out chardet. I've tried iconv before, but I find it difficult to locate the correspondence between `file` output and the exact name of the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(file,encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: yes, didn't work, also tried `encoding="ISO-8859-1"`